# onChange event is not being triggered in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to make the onChange event of the following componenet to fire but it does not. When I type in the seach box nothing is printed on the console. No change is fired

```
const Search = () => {
    let history = useHistory()
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (search) {
            console.log("typing..")
            history.push(`/?search=${search}`)
        } else {
            history.push(history.push(history.location.pathname))
        }
    }
    return (
        <Form.Group controlId='searchbox' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Control
                className="auth-input" 
                type='text'
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            >
            </Form.Control>
            <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
        </Form.Group>

    )
}
export default Search
```

```
const Home =()=>{
    return (<div><Search /><div>)
}
```

export default Home
I still can't identify where the error is. How do I get it working?

Comment: From where you are importing form control ?

Comment: form.control is the input field. I import this component I posted into an fresh component then trying to find out if the onChange will trigger. No other thing is in the component where I'm importing this particular component I posted in the question

Comment: Please add snippet from where you are importing form

Comment: I have added it. It's that home component underneath the first component in the post. It's only the thing I imported in the component. It's a fresh component

Comment: Check your codebase in depth. Form.Control is custom or 3rd party plugin. Understand which library you are using and then you will get an idea on events

Comment: I'm using react-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming Form.Control is a custom control or a third-party control, hence you cannot convert it to a controlled input. You could try creating a ref and get the value from the ref in the onChange event handler. If the custom control is not a third party control, then you could add the onChange handler inside the Form.Control component and pass a function reference to the control.

Edit:

Here is your solution : https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mclean-4jusl?file=/src/App.js

In case you see an error in the sandbox, refresh the page. There seems to be some error with codesandbox.

**Explanation**:

Create a ref to access the input using useRef:

```
const controlref = useRef();
```

Pass the ref to the control:

```
<Form.Control
  onChange={handleChange}
  **ref={controlref}**
  type="text"
  placeholder="search..."
/>
```

Get the value in onChange using the ref:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(controlref.current.value);
    setSearch(controlref.current.value);
  };
```

Comment: I just added example of how I'm importing it.

Comment: You need to provide your code for Form.Control component.

Comment: If Form.Control is 3rd party control then let me know i will give you solution accordingly.

Comment: nothing like From.Control component. That Form.Control you find there is a way of writing `<input />` Field in react-bootstrap

Comment: There you go. So, it's a 3rd party control :)

Comment: the stuff isn't working still

Comment: Check my explanation and make sure you have implemented all the steps.

Comment: Thank you @Abhish Abraham. It worked on the console, but introducing the useRef, I'm not able to make the history.push to be triggered when onChange is fired, that's my aim in the work, just as you can see from the handleSubmit function. I haven't used useRef before, but if it can enable me to fire history.push then it'll be fine. But that doesn't work right now

Comment: This is outside of the topic of this thread. If your onChange issue is fixed, then mark this thread as answered. What exactly are you trying to achieve by using history.push ?

Comment: I have fixed the issue anywhere. But you also have a point

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, html "input" is a self closing element.

Secondly, You have missed the "value" inside the Input component.

Your code:

```
<Form.Control
    className="auth-input" 
    type='text'
    placeholder="Search..."
    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
></Form.Control>
```

Solution:

```
<Form.Control
    className="auth-input" 
    type='text'
    placeholder="Search..."
    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
    value={search}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Shafayet2368. When I removed the closing tag and added value attributes to form control, the the issue persists.

Comment: It's good practice to close the element, but the value property is not required. You're more than likely not using value. I imagine you're probably calling a function in an onChange event that sets the state using useState()

Answer (score 0):

Try using event onInput instead:

```
<Form.Control
    className="auth-input" 
    type='text'
    placeholder="Search..."
    onInput={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
 />
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander Staroselsky. I replaced onChange with onInput but the issue remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I made this silly mistake. The issue is due to the fact that I omitted the  tag and placed the submit button within the <Form.Group>  which doesn't have the property to handle onSubmit event. So I changed this

```
    return (
        <Form.Group controlId='searchbox' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Control
                className="auth-input" 
                type='text'
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            >
            </Form.Control>
            <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
        </Form.Group>

    )
```

It was modified to this:

```
    return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <Form.Group controlId='searchbox' >
            <Form.Control
                className="auth-input" 
                type='text'
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            >
            </Form.Control>
            <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>

    )
```